# Pandas read_table use first column as index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a little bit of a problem here. I have a txt file containing lines of the form (let's say for line 1):

```
id1-a1-b1-c1
```

I want to load it in a data frame using pandas with the index being the id's and the columns name being 'A', 'B', 'C' and the values the corresponding ai, bi, ci

at the end I want the dataframe to look like:

```
    'A'   'B'  'C'
id1  a1    b1   c1
id2  a2    b2   c2
...   ...   ...  ...
```

I may want to read by chunks in the file is large but let's assume I read at once:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    table = pd.read_table(f, sep='-', index_col=0, header=None,   lineterminator='\n')
```

and rename the columns

```
table.columns = ['A','B','C']
```

my current output is something like:

```
    'A'   'B'  'C'
0
id1  a1    b1   c1
id2  a2    b2   c2
...   ...   ...  ...
```

there is an extra row that I can't explain

Thanks

**EDIT**

when I try to add the field

```
chunksize=20
```

and after doing:

```
for chunk in table:
    print(chunk)
```

I get the following error:

```
pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on source failed. Try engine='python'.
```

Comment: What is the current output like?

Comment: check out the `skiprows` parameter to the `read_table`

Comment: Are you deriving the column names from the input file, or are they static?

Answer (score 25):

If you know the column names before the file is read, pass the list using `names` parameter of [read_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_table.html):

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    table = pd.read_table(f, sep='-', index_col=0, header=None, names=['A','B','C'],
                          lineterminator='\n')
```

Which outputs:

```
      A   B   C
id1  a1  b1  c1
id2  a2  b2  c2
```

Comment: Hi, yes it works thanks! However when I try to add chunksize=20 let's say it raises an error:    pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on source failed. Try engine='python'.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's helpful.